# Sum Cell Values Until Blank Cells With VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code on the internet. How do I get the sum value to appear in the empty cell above the cells containing consecutive values. I'm thinking of running the code from the last row. Thank for all

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3963-excel-sum-until-blank.html

```
Sub InsertTotals()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim i, j, StartRow, StartCol As Integer
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the cells:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    StartRow = xRg.Row
    StartCol = xRg.Column
    For i = StartCol To xRg.Columns.Count + StartCol - 1
        For j = xRg.Row To xRg.Rows.Count + StartRow - 1
            If Cells(j, i) = "" Then
                Cells(j, i).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(StartRow, i).Address & ":" & Cells(j - 1, i).Address & ")"
                StartRow = j + 1
            End If
        Next
        StartRow = xRg.Row
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Like that :D   https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5SwL.png

Comment: Have you looked on here for similar questions?

Comment: I have searched for similar topics, but to no avail

Comment: How does the software run from the bottom position?